how to define a process with interaction between several forms according to W3C WoT?
W3C WoT specifies basic building blocks for communication with Things (like forms and  Protocols bindings).
How these features can be applied in combination if complete interaction with a Thing requires a sequence of the  calls with parameters passing between them ?
For example, let´s the Thing  has two properties (forms):
{
    "@context": "https://www.w3.org/2022/wot/td/v1.1",
    // ...
    "properties": {
        "measurementsIds": {
            // ...
            "uriVariables": {
                "start": { 
                    "type": "date", 
                   "description": "Start date of the Measurements ID set" },
                "finish": { 
                    "type": "date", 
                    "description": "End date of Measurements ID set" }
            },
            "forms": [{
              "href": "http://thing.org/measurementsID/{?start,finish}",
              "htv:methodName": "GET"
            }]
        },
        // ...
    },
        "measurement": {
            // ...
            "uriVariables": {
                "id": { 
                    "type": "integer", 
                   "description": "ID of the measurement" }
            },
            "forms": [{
              "href": "http://thing.org/measurement/{?id}",
              "htv:methodName": "GET"
            }]
        },
        // ...
    },



    // ...
}

How I can specify a combined behaviour (a kind of the process or a transaction) when measurementsIds should be called first,  and the response data (ie. a list of JSON objects with ID) is used to provide values for the variable ?id in a sequence of measurement calls ?

There is sadly no standardized solution for this. I have done research work in this direction some time ago that I can share but you either need a state machine or a list of transitions.

Specification of the state machine is not a limitation, because the logic of interaction has to be defined in advance. So, I wonder to know any practical solution for such specific case.

https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-31585-6_3 is what I have done in this direction. For anything more complex, I would recommend defining a state machine in something like SCXML and treating the state transitions as actions
